# unable to connect to jenkins agent via ssh

Tags: jenkins

I've got a 'build' i need to run on a dev box.   I can do what i need fine by ssh'ing into that box from jenkins and running some bash scripts.  but i'd like to use pipeline stages/steps instead to do this.  To i tried creating an Agent/Node for this purpose
On  my jenkins box i generated an rsa key using

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

i then created a credentials for this key followed by a Node agent that uses that key.
I also added the .pub content to the authorized_keys on the target box i would like to execute these pipeline steps on.
When i try starting that agent using the Jenkins UI, the error is:

> PEM problem: it is of unknown type. Supported algorithms are
> :[ssh-ed25519, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,
> ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, rsa-sha2-256, rsa-sha2-512, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss

```
java.io.IOException: Publickey authentication failed. at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePublicKey(AuthenticationManager.java:349) at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.authenticateWithPublicKey(Connection.java:472) at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.java:110) at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:431) at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.authenticate(SSHAuthenticator.java:468) at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:878) at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.lambda$launch$0(SSHLauncher.java:434) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by: java.io.IOException: PEM problem: it is of unknown type. Supported algorithms are :[ssh-ed25519, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, rsa-sha2-256, rsa-sha2-512, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss] at com.trilead.ssh2.crypto.PEMDecoder.decodeKeyPair(PEMDecoder.java:482) at com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePublicKey(AuthenticationManager.java:290)
```

I've tried generating keys with 'rsa' 'ed25519' and all of them give the same error. What am i doing wrong here? am i going about this incorrectly?
thanks

Comment: Could you manually verify that the new key you generated for Jenkins works as expected? If it does then make sure there are no extra characters saved in the private key field in Jenkins. It should work.

Comment: Would you please help clarify are you talking about the [Azure DevOps pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops) or the [Jenkins Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#overview)? According to the above content, your issue seems to be that the agent cannot be successfully set up in Jenkins instead of Azure DevOps agent pool. Is this correct?

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT Jenkins, not azure